# kdb+/q:How does one convert a utc timestamp to a datetime?

Tags: kdb

How could one convert the following timestamp `t:1595779091979` into its equivalent `datetime$() representation (UTC)?

For instance if one tries to do so using the following.

```
q) `datetime$t
    0000.00.00T00:00:00.000

q) `timestamp$t
    2000.01.01D00:26:35.779091979
```

(Both are incorrect, the time should be 2020.07.26D...)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timestamp `1595779091979` looks like milliseconds since 1970 epoch.  If you drop the millis - the conversion is simply

```
 q)1970.01.01+0D00:00:01*1595779091
2020.07.26D15:58:11.000000000
```

or keeping the millis:

```
 q)1970.01.01+0D00:00:00.001*1595779091979
2020.07.26D15:58:11.979000000
```

Finally, you can add the following definition to your utility library

```
ts:1970.01.01+0D00:00:00.001*
```

and use it in your code whenever you need conversion

```
 q)ts 1595779091979
2020.07.26D15:58:11.979000000
```

**Update:** A slightly shorter solution can be written as

```
ts:1970.01.01D+1000000*
```